# When to use upstart for Tomcat vs. Tomcat's Daemon Mode?

Tags: linux, tomcat, daemon

According to the [Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html#Unix_daemon), Tomcat can be set up - on Linux/Unix - to run as a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29). However, to behave as a daemon, special configuration is required beyond the defaults that Tomcat ships with.

My understanding of a true *NIX **daemon** is that it is a background, *non-interactive* program, usually owned by the `init` process. Typically, daemons do scheduled background work and are never driven by input by an actual user.

Here is the root of my question: it seems that Tomcat can be given daemon-like behavior from it's own Daemon Mode (first link above) or via any number of built-in Linux tools (`upstart`, `init.d`, `systemd`, etc.). So this means we have 4 possible scenarios here:

[image]

On one hand, we may choose to use Tomcat's Daemon Mode or not. We also may choose to use a built-in Linux tool or not.

What I'm looking for is this: **What use cases necessitate each of the 4 scenarios depicted above?** That is:

1. When do I use Tomcat's Daemon Mode, *and* use, say, `upstart`?
2. When do I not use Tomcat's Daemon Mode, but use `upstart`?
3. When do I use Tomcat's Daemon Mode, but *not* use `upstart`?
4. When do I use neither?

Obviously, in those questions, you can replace `upstart` with any other tool (`systemd`, etc.).

Comment: Daemons *can* communicate with the outside world. I don't know what made you think they can't.

Comment: Thanks @Biffen (+1) - ok, so then I guess the root of my question is: what is the difference between Tomcat running as a non-daemon vs Tomcat running as a daemon? What benefits does "daemon mode" add?

Comment: Typically you'd want Tomcat to start when the server starts, without you having to log in and start it manually, as well as to continue to run when you log out. I guess that's daemons in a nutshell. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)).

Comment: Thanks again @Biffern (+1) - it should be noted that the link you just posted is the same one that I posted above ;-) **More importantly** - why couldn't I just use Upstart or `init.d` to treat Tomcat as a Linux daemon? Something like [this](http://raibledesigns.com/tomcat/boot-howto.html). When would I use Tomcat's built-in daemon mode vs something like that link (start/stop scripts, Linux daemon via `init.d`)? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, should've checked that link. Anyway, what makes you think you shouldn't use upstart or init.d? It's the common way to do it and I'd say a recommended way (although you might want to move to systemd; upstart probably won't be around for much longer). In fact if you install Tomcat from a repository you *should* get everything set up for you, so that something like `service tomcat start` (or a reboot) should start it.

Comment: Thanks (yet again!) @Biffen (+1) - please see my update and drawing. It's not that I think I *shouldn't* use upstart/init.d/systemd/etc. - **it's that I'm confused as to when to use any of these vs. when to use Tomcat's daemon mode**.  Thoughts?